# SXA indexes not created after installing 10.3

Tags: sxa, indexing, installation, index

I have installed `10.3` on my `Windows 11 Pro` machine by running the PowerShell script - `XP0-SingleDeveloper.ps1`.

However, that doesn't install SXA.
So, I had to install separate packages for SXA & PowerShell Extensions.

I can now see the options to create `Tenant` & `Tenant Folder` in CMS.
But when rebuilding indexes, the sxa indexes are not listed.
I was looking for `myinstance_sxa_master_index` & `myinstance_sxa_web_index`.

When I open the Solr portal (`8.11.2`), even there, these are not listed.

1. Is this expected?
2. Do I really need these indexes?
3. If yes, what additional steps should I perform to get them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not uncommon for SXA indexes to not appear after installation, even if you have installed SXA separately. This is because the SXA indexes are not created by default when you install Sitecore.

**To create your SOLR SXA core:**

1. Navigate to your Solr folder (`<path_to_solr>\server\solr`) and Duplicate the core directory created for `sitecore_master_index` (or company_name_master_index) twice and rename it to:

• `sitecore_sxa_master_index`

• `sitecore_sxa_web_index`.

2. In those two folders, remove everything except the conf directory.
3. On the Solr web interface, click Core Admin, and click Add Core to add
   `sitecore_sxa_master_index`. Do the same for `sitecore_sxa_web_index`.

> Make sure that the names of the Solr cores you created match the
> settings for sitecore_sxa_master_index and sitecore_sxa_web_index in
> Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Solr.config. If you have to rename the cores > you have also to change the id’s in in > Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Solr.config

[image]

4. In Sitecore, log in to the Launchpad, and open the Control Panel.
5. In the Indexing section, click Populate Solr Managed Schema.
6. In the Schema Populate dialog, select `sitecore_sxa_master_index` and
   `sitecore_sxa_web_index`, and click Populate.
7. In the Indexing section, click `Indexing Manager`.
8. In the Indexing Manager dialog box, select `sitecore_sxa_master_index` and `sitecore_sxa_web_index`, and click Rebuild.

The reason for creating the cores in SXA is to enable its functionalities to work properly. Failure to create these cores will result in exceptions being thrown when attempting to use SXA or SXA-related functionalities. Therefore, it is necessary to create the cores in order to ensure the smooth functioning of SXA.

Comment: Even after creating the Solr folders and the cores in solr folder with the name `sitecore_sxa_master_index`, I still do not see it listed in CMS indexing dialog. I have also logged out & in. The name of the id in the config is the same - `sitecore_sxa_master_index`.

Comment: you need to restart solr service and do the IIS reset.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you install with a SXA module normally it creates a `sitecore_sxa_master_index` and `sitecore_sxa_web_index`. Patch you can find out at `wwebroot\YourInstanceFolder\App_Config\Modules\SXA\z.Foundation.Overrides\Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Solr.config` and respective Solr folders/configurations are created too.
2. Yes, It required the indexes to be there to perform the `SXA` in the desired way. If you don't have the index it could impact the functionality like search and performance as well as general exceptions.
3. You need to configure SXA indexing. Refer to the official link to Configure SXA indexing. [Configure SXA indexing](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/103/sitecore-experience-accelerator/configure-sxa-indexing.html)

Or another easy way to create sxa cors is by using [Sifon](https://sifon.uk/)  by Martin Miles.

https://blog.martinmiles.net/post/the-easiest-way-of-installing-solr-cores-for-sxa-search

Hope it helps!